# Facebook app and session handling

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, session, facebook-javascript-sdk

What is the way to do the app logout when the user is logged out from Facebook?

Let's consider the following situation: I've got the app that build into the webshops, so I somehow need to know the login status of the user. When the user logs into facebook and then into my app, he can 'save' or 'bookmark' the page. There's an option - to provide the logout button which logs out from the app, and then from facebook.

But my problem is the opposite: how to detect if the user has logged out from facebook - inside my app, which is built into the webshop? There's no way to detect it from the backend, only the js. Can I somehow build in the facebook login status change into my js code so it will do the check right away when my js snippet has loaded on a website?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple graph api request like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token={your%20access%20token}
```

If user is logged in then you will receive a response with user information otherwise you will get a response as follows

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467
   }
}
```

Using this you can differentiate whether is user is logged in into fb or not.

Thanks,
Pranav

Comment: This does not seem to work, since the AccessToken is not revoked. The debugger shows that it's still valid for 2 months:

Expires 1437154288 (in about 2 months)

Answer (score 0):

Could not find any reasonable solution, so did the following:

- every request is directed to the app
- on the app landing page Facebook JS SDK checks the login status and handles everything